# Error conectando a la base de datos con mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un problema con este codigo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $db_host="localhost"; 
    $db_usuario="root";
    $db_contra="";
    $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
    $consulta="SELECT* FROM datospersonales";
    $resultados=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
    $fila=mysqli_fetch_row($resultados);
    echo $fila[0];
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Me marca este error: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_row(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\basededatos.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\basededatos.php(15): mysqli_fetch_row(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\basededatos.php on line 15
Soy principiante y no entiendo que esta mal

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no le estas pasando la base de datos a la que conectarse, tienes que pasarla de forma que tu código quede así:

`$conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra, "database");`

Con eso el código ya debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Te aconsejo que revises siempre la documentación de aquellas funciones que estás usando. Es bastante clara y en castellano y con buenos ejemplos por lo general.

En el caso de  [`mysqli_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php) está claramente indicado que necesita **un cuarto parámetro** que sería la base de datos a la que quieres conectar.

En el hermano mayor de `mysqli` este cuarto parámetro no era admitido y debías seleccionar la BD después de conectar. Quizá tu confusión venga de ahí.

Por otra parte, si tu consulta trae varias filas, la forma de lectura que tienes ahora te mostrará una sola fila. Si quieres mostrar todas las filas, tendrás que mover el puntero de los datos en un bucle para irlos sacando.

Eso está claramente explicado también [en la documentación (**Ejemplo 1**) de `mysqli_fetch_row`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) que el fetch que usas aquí. Y vale para los otros fetch de que dispone `mysqli`.

Aplicando lo dicho, el código quedaría así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    $db_host="localhost"; 
    $db_usuario="root";
    $db_contra="";
    /*
      Pon en la variable el nombre de la base de datos 
      */
    $db_name="AQUÍELNOMBREREALDETUBASEDEDATOS";

    /*
      Pasamos $db_name como cuarto parámetro
      */
    $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra,$db_name);
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM datospersonales";
    $resultados=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_row($resultados)) {
      /*
        El índice 0 significa la 1ª columna 
        si hay una segunda tienes que usar $fila[1]
        y así sucesivamente....
        PHP_EOL es un salto de línea
        */
      echo $fila[0].PHP_EOL;   
    }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Es mucho mas sencillo usar PDO**

Config.php

```
<?php

define('HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DATABASE', 'database');

class   MysqlDB{
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $database;
    private $conexion;

    function __construct()
    {
         $this->host=HOST;
         $this->user=USER;
         $this->password=PASSWORD;
         $this->database=DATABASE;
    }

    public function ConnDB(){
        $this->conexion= new mysqli($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
    }
    public function CloseDB(){
        $this->conexion->mysqli_close();
    }

}
```

?>

**Lo implementas de esta forma**

```
 <?php
require_once("config.php");

//Creas una nueva instancia
$connect = MysqlDB();

//Creas una nueva conexion
$connect = connDB();

?>
```